# Find distinct documents with max value of a field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have thousands of documents in MongoDB with some of the sample as below:

```
{"title":"Foo", "hash": "1234567890abcedf", "num_sold": 49, 
"created": "2013-03-09 00:00:00"}

{"title":"Bar", "hash": "1234567890abcedf", "num_sold": 55, 
"created": "2013-03-11 00:00:00"}

{"title":"Baz", "hash": "1234567890abcedf", "num_sold": 55,
 "created": "2013-03-10 00:00:00"}

{"title":"Spam", "hash": "abcedef1234567890", "num_sold": 20,
 "created": "2013-03-11 00:00:00"}

{"title":"Eggs", "hash": "abc1234567890def", "num_sold": 20,
 "created": "2013-03-11 00:00:00"}
```

Is it possible to select all documents with distinct `hash` which has the max of `num_sold` and if there is more than one document with same `num_sold`, select the latest document from the `created` field.

I use PyMongo for the client.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am no Python expert so I will write this in JavaScript. You can do this with the aggregation framework using the `$sort`, `$group` and `$first` opreators:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$sort: {created:-1}},
    {$group: {_id: '$hash', num_sold: {$first: '$num_sold'}, _id_seen: {$first: '$_id'}}}
])
```

Essentially what I do is sort the incoming documents by their created date DESC and then I group on hash, concatenating two duplicate hashes and then I get the first result of the sorted group, which should be the newest document.

References:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/#_S_first

Comment: I tried this, but it selects only the `hash` field, but I require the `_id` of the object to correctly select the document.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think that works (atleast selects the correct num of docs). I will mark your answer as accepted after I check the IDs of the documents.