# Get the max of distinct documents and return all fields

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have some documents similar to this structure:

```
[
    {"file_base": "file_1", "version": 100, "file_name": "file_1_100.txt"},
    {"file_base": "file_1", "version": 200, "file_name": "file_1_200.txt"},
    {"file_base": "file_1", "version": 300, "file_name": "file_1_300.txt"},
    {"file_base": "file_2", "version": 100, "file_name": "file_2_100.txt"},
    {"file_base": "file_2", "version": 200, "file_name": "file_2_200.txt"},
    {"file_base": "file_2", "version": 300, "file_name": "file_2_300.txt"}
]
```

I need to create a query that gets the latest version of every file and returns all of the fields. So far, I have this:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$sort': {'version': -1}},
    {'$match': {}},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$file_base',
        'highest_version': {'$first': '$version'}
    }
    }
]

results = files_collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

This almost returns what I need. It returns:

```
{'_id': 'file_2', 'highest_version': 300}
{'_id': 'file_1', 'highest_version': 300}
```

But I need all of the fields. In the real-life version of this problem, there are many more fields for each file. So in the context of this example, I would need something like:

```
{'_id': 'file_2', 'highest_version': 300, 'file_name': 'file_2_300.txt'}
{'_id': 'file_1', 'highest_version': 300, 'file_name': 'file_1_300.txt'}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334408/find-distinct-documents-with-max-value-of-a-field-in-mongodb) is similar, but it only returns the grouped_by field and the max field. I need them all. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like `{'$group': {
        '_id': '$file_base',
        'file': {'$first': '$$ROOT'}
    }` More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-documents-by-author

Comment: I noticed the '$$ROOT' in the Mongo docs, but in PyMongo I am getting the error: "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."

I saw some other stackoverflow posts that it has to do with the mongo version, but I am using 3.4, so not sure what the deal is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you need :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {'$sort': {'version': -1}},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$file_base',
        'highest_version': { '$first' : '$version'},
        'file_name': { '$first' : '$file_name'},
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't even think to use $first more than once... I keep trying to somehow pass it multiple fields. It would be nice if there were a way to get all of the fields with one call. But I think this will work... Thanks